# Powershell : How to install PSReadline module in an offline computer

Tags: powershell, psreadline

I need to install PSReadline module in an offline computer

with
Windows 7 SP1
and powershell 5.1

I have another computer that is connected to the internet.

Could you please explain how to download the relevant files 
and how to install them on the offline computer?

Comment: You may find [this information at Microsoft Docs on manually downloading and installing packages from the Gallery](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/powershell/scripting/gallery/how-to/working-with-packages/manual-download) to be useful.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

If you download it to an online computer the module will be in one of your module paths - type:

```
$env:PSModulePath
```

...this will list all the possible paths, just search for the correct folder and copy it to the offline computer in one of its module paths. If there are any dependencies these will need to be copied also.